# AWS, SQS, calculate visabilityTimeout for 10 messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, billing

I have the code:

```
val messageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest().withQueueUrl(queueUrl).withVisibilityTimeout(8000).withMaxNumberOfMessages(10)
val messages = sqs.receiveMessage(messageRequest).getMessages.asScala
```

My lambda can work a maximum of 13min 33sec (it is 800sec)

I take 10 messages from the SQS at a time

I want to calculate VisibilityTimeout correctly

I use formula:

*"lambda timeout" (800sec) *  MaxNumberOfMessages (10) = 8000 sec*

800 seconds for each message

**1. Have I counted VisibilityTimeout correctly?**

**2. Does VisibilityTimeout change affect billing?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visibility timeout is how long SQS will keep a message *invisible* to any consumer after it has been delivered to one consumer, waiting for that consumer to process and delete it.  If a message, once delivered, is not deleted from the queue by the consumer that received it within the allowed window, then it becomes visible again and will be delivered again, when visibility timeout expires.

In the scenario you described, the correct value is still 800, because the visibility timeout applies to each message, individually, but starting at the same time and running concurrently.  Your code will terminate after 800 seconds and the messages need to become visible again when that amount of time elapses.  If set to 8000 seconds, if your code terminates after 800 seconds, then the messages will all remain invisible for an additional 7200 seconds before the timeout expires.

Visibility timeout has no direct effect on billing.